# Integer to Roman "incompatible types: int cannot be converted to boolean [in MainClass.java]"

Tags: java, int, roman-numerals

I want to convert integers to roman numerals, but I receive an error `incompatible types: int cannot be converted to boolean [in MainClass.java]`. It refers to for statement, but I can not see what is wrong.

```
public String intToRoman(int num) {
    if (num < 0 || num > 3999) 
        return Integer.toString(-1);
    int nums[] = {1,4,5,9,10,40,50,90,100,400,500,900,1000}; 
    String[] syms = {"I","IV","V","IX","X","XL","L","XC","C","CD","D","CM","M"}; 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int n=0;


    for(int i = 12; 0 ; i--) {

        int res=0;

        if(num > nums[i]) {

            res = num / nums[i];

            for(int j=1 ; res ; j++) {
                sb.append(syms[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: for(int i = 12; 0 ; i--) and for(int j=1 ; res ; j++) here zero and res what it means ? and if possible can share main method also.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm was pretty close, first there is no roman numeral for zero; so test that `num` (or `value`) is at least one. Second, I renamed `num` to `value` because `nums` makes it difficult to differentiate. Next, loops require a `boolean` terminating condition. Here, you want to terminate the outer loop when `i` is less than zero and the inner loop when `j` is greater than (or equal to) `value / nums[i]`. Finally, since you use no instance state, I made the method `static`. Like,

```
public static String intToRoman(int value) {
    if (value < 1 || value > 3999) {
        return "-1";
    }
    int nums[] = { 1, 4, 5, 9, 10, 40, 50, 90, 100, 400, 500, 900, 1000 };
    String[] syms = { "I", "IV", "V", "IX", "X", "XL", "L", "XC", "C", "CD", 
            "D", "CM", "M" };
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = nums.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (value >= nums[i]) {
            for (int j = 0; j < (value / nums[i]); j++) {
                sb.append(syms[i]);
            }
            value %= nums[i];
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Which I tested, like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
        System.out.println(intToRoman(i));
    }
}
```

And it appears to work correctly here.

Answer (score 0):

In `for loop` the first segment is an initialization, second is the condition, and third is an increment or decrement in the variable.
In your second for loop, you did not mention a condition which should result in `boolean` value `true`/`false`. But you mentioned `res` which is of type `int`.
Please rectify the code and it will work.
Go [here](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_for_loop.asp) for more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

```
1.The first statement declares an int variable named i and assigns it the value 20. This statement is only executed once, when the for loop starts.
2.The second statement compares the value and The second statement in a for loop is a condition statement and needs to be a boolean. This statement is executed before each repetition of the for loop.
3.The third statement increments the value of i/j. This statement is also executed once per iteration of the for loop, after the body of the for loop is executed.

These statements each have a different role in the execution of the for loop. 
These roles are:

1.Loop initializer
2.Loop condition
3.Post iteration operation
```